# Looking for an "example database"

Tags: database, web-services, semantics, data-retrieval

I'm currently working on a semantic web project to enrich web services with semantic meta information.

Therefore, I'm looking for another information source to gain more information (esp. examples, instances).

The problem: Given I have a label (like "zip code", "email address", "surname", "music instrument", ...), us there any good database that can give me at least one (good) example for these terms automatically? (like "music instrument" - "piano")

I'm currently using a combination of WordNet, DBpedia and the YAGO project - it works but there are often some difficulties using them - especially, when I need examples for numbers (like IP addresses).

Of course, I could use some manual lists to lookup an example for special cases (like IP address) but I would prefer a fully automated way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried http://www.freebase.com ?

Here is what it returns for musical instrument.
http://www.freebase.com/view/music/instrument

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for this note. I've currently implemented a tool that uses a combination of different sources to do that. Freebase is one of the services I use. Some others are WordNet and DBpedia. It is still a hard task but the combination of different sources gives valuable results.

Comment: Ok, the only other thing I can think of is using a framework like Apache UIMA to glue together the different results.  I don't know of any IP address converters.